# Why does my else statement execute even after if statement condition has been met?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I'm using a for loop to search a text for a value usinf if else statement inside the for loop. Even when my search condition has been met, my else block is also being executed.

This is the text I am using to search for the value:

SKU Product Desc. Pack/ Size QtyUOM Price Extension
1 WL140.111 Clam Tuatua Medium NZ / 20-34 pcs per kilogram / 30.00 KG HK$109.25 HK$3,277.50
Locations: KIT - Butchery (8%) 30.00 Edit Line Edit Alloc

This is my code:

```
whole_details = re.compile(r'Item([\$\w\s\.\/\-\,:()%]+)(?:Sub Total)')
wd = whole_details.search(text)
wd_text = wd.group(1)

products = ["Yoghurt Passionfruit Organic", "Yoghurt Plain Organic Vegan", "Clam Tuatua Medium 20-", "Clam Tuatua Medium NZ /", "Oyster Pacific NZ /"]

for product in products:
    if wd_text.find(product) != -1:
        re_qty = re.compile(rf'{product}\s([\d.]+)')
        qty_search = re_qty.search(wd_text)
        qty = qty_search.group(1)
        print("Product Description : " + product)
        print("Quantity : " + qty)
else:
    print("No product")
```

This the output I am getting now:

```
Product Description : Clam Tuatua Medium NZ /
Quantity : 20
No products
```

Comment: This is Python and indentation matters. See that your else is not indented properly as compared to your if

Comment: you may want to have 'if' and 'else' with same indentation?

Comment: A `for` loop can *also* have an `else` clause, which executes then when the loop completes by exhausting its iterator, rather than encountering a `break` statement.

Comment: if my else statement is aligned with if statement then the else block is executed multiple times before reaching the if statement ie, while iterating through each product it executes the else block. So basically the else block executes no matter what.
@chepner where should I put the break statement. I tried it after the if statement. But then it won't execute if I have multiple matches.